# How can I take an Image from SD card? And How to convert to an String (base64)

Tags: java, android, image, base64, sd-card

I need Access Images from the sd card. I have their path. How could I Take them and convert to an String base 64?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this... then, you can read the file as you want.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
String encodeFileToBase64Binary = encodeFileToBase64Binary(yourFile);

private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(fileName);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    return encodedString;
}

private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```